# how to print database diagram sql

Tags: printing, ssms

I would like to print a SQL Server database diagram. I'm using SQL Server Management Studio, I right clicked on the diagram, and selected "View Page Breaks".

I wanted to have the diagram in A3 Format but when I tried to print it had 4 pages. 
Is there a way to print the whole diagram in just one page?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Set the page zoom level on the print properties page (in addition to setting the page size to A3).

Switching back to the diagram with 'View Page Breaks' selected will show you when you have all the tables positioned properly onto one page.

Answer (score 52):

On SQL Server Management Studio

In the Database Diagram, right click and select 'View Page Breaks'

Then from main window menu select, File > Page Setup

Select Page Size and Orientation - A3 and Landscape are most likely best options.

And **Print Scale** - this is the % value that should *hopefully* enable you to fit all tables onto one page.

Comment: The additional note about the Print Scale makes this a very useful answer.

Comment: the "Print Scale" option is also on the File > Page Setup

Comment: Hence line #3 and #5